# Prove this by the principle of mathematical induction.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $S_r(n)=1^r+2^r+\cdots+n^r$, then prove that
$S_r(n) \geq \int_0^nx^r\,dx$.
Please help me to solve this problem. I am not able to prove that $P(k+1)$ is true using $P(k)$.

Answer (score 3):

One way to prove the induction step is to show that $(k+1)^r\gt \int_{k}^{k+1} x^r\,dx$. (We need $r\gt 0$.)

To do this, draw a picture. On the interval $[k,k+1]$, the function $x^r$ is $\le (k+1)^r$, so $(k+1)^r\ge \int_{k}^{k+1} x^r\,dx$. Geometrically, $(k+1)^r$ is the area of the rectangle with base $[k,k+1]$ and height $(k+1)^r$. And on the interval, the function $x^r$ is an increasing function that is $k^r$ at the beginning and $(k+1)^r$ at the end. So the region below $y=x^r$, above the $x$-axis, from $k$ to $k+1$ is contained in the rectangle.

And on the first half of the interval we have $x^r\lt (k+1)^r$, so the inequality is strict.